# mysql.connector error(?) with python 3.10 on visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I was working on a python program for running a simple rudimentary library list, and, for some reason, me, as well as a friend of mine, recieved 2 errors:

> PS C:\Users\Rotten> &
> C:/Users/Rotten/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
> "c:/Users/Rotten/Downloads/import mysql.connector as sqltor.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
> line 523, in cmd_query
> self._cmysql.query(query,
> _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(70),salt varchar(70))' at
> line 1

and this too

> File "c:\Users\Rotten\Downloads\import mysql.connector as
> sqltor.py", line 7, in 
> cursor.execute("create table users(username varchar(20),key varchar(70),salt varchar(70));")   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py",
> line 269, in execute
> result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,   File "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
> line 528, in cmd_query
> raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg, mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> 'varchar(70),salt varchar(70))' at line 1

```
import mysql.connector as sqltor
import hashlib
import os
from datetime import date
mycon=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="123456",database="library")
cursor=mycon.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table users(username varchar(20),key varchar(70),salt varchar(70));")
cursor.execute("create table userlist(username varchar(20),book varchar(200));")
def users(username,password):
    cursor.execute("select * from users where username={}".format(username))
    data=cursor.fetchone()
    if data=="(NULL)":
        return False
    elif data==True:
        salt=data[2]
        key=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
        if data[1]==key:
            return True
        elif data[1]!=key:
            return False
        else:
            print("error")
    else:
        print("error")
        return False
def userlist(username,bookcode,bookborrowdate):
    booktick=cursor.execute("Select book from userlist where username={}".format(username))
    if booktick!="NULL":
        bookdict=booktick
    else:
        bookdict={}
    bookdict.update({'bookcode':'bookborrowdate'})
    cursor.execute("insert into userlist values('{}','{}');".format(username,bookdict))
    mycon.commit()
def userfull():
    cursor.execute("select book from userlist;")
    bookdata=cursor.fetchone()
    bookneed=bookdata[0]
    for key, value in bookneed.items():
        print(key, ' : ', value)
def checkkey():
    cursor.execute("select count(username) from users, where username='{}';".format(username))
    if 1 in cursor.fetchone():
        return True
    elif 0 in cursor.fetchone():
        return False
    else:
        print("error")
        return False
def userret(username,bookcode):
    cursor.execute("select book from userlist where username={};".format(username))
    bookreturn=cursor.fetchone()
    bookretex=bookreturn[0]
    if bookcode in bookretex:
        borrowdate=bookretex.get(bookcode)
        pricecheck=date.today
        dayspast=(pricecheck-borrowdate).days
        rate=dayspast*0.5
        del bookretex[bookcode]
        return rate
def adduser(username,password):
    salt = os.urandom(32)
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
    cursor.execute("insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'".format(username,key,salt))
    mycon.commit()
while True:
    print("WELCOME TO THE LIBRARY SYSTEM")
    print("1.LOGIN")
    print("2.NEW USER")
    print("3.EXIT")
    ch=int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    if ch==1:
        print("WELCOME, PLEASE ENTER YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
        username=input("Enter username:")
        password=input("Enter password:")
        users(username,password)
        if users==True:
            while True:
                print("Welcome back ",username,". What do you want to do? \n")
                print("1.Add book to borrow")
                print("2.Return book borrowed")
                print("3.Check existing borrowed book(s)")
                print("4.Logout")
                usch=int(input("Enter your choice: "))
                if usch==1:
                    while True:
                        bookcode=input("Enter code of book to be borrowed")
                        bookborrowdate=date.today()
                        userlist(username,bookcode,bookborrowdate)
                        td=timedelta(10)
                        print("Please return this book by",bookborrowdate+td)
                        choice=input("Continue?[y/n]")
                        if choice in 'Yy':
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                elif usch==2:
                    while True:
                        bookcode=input("Enter code of borrowed book to be returned")
                        returnticket=userret(username,bookcode)
                        print("Book returned, please pay Rs.",returnticket," at the reception")
                        returncookie=input("continue? [y/n]: ")
                        if returncookie in "Yy":
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                elif usch==3:
                    userfull()
                elif usch==4:
                    print("Logging out of ",username,"...")
                    username=None
                    password=None
                    break
                else:
                    print("Wrong input, try again")
        elif users==False:
            print("Username or password wrong, please try again")
        else:
            if mycon.is_connected():
                print("Unknown error, please try again")
            else:
                print("Error connecting to database, please try again")
    elif ch==2:
        while True:
            print("WELCOME, NEW USER, PLEASE ENTER A VALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
            usertest=input("Enter username: ")
            usertest2=usertest
            checkkey(usertest)
            if checkkey==True:
                password=input("Enter Password: ")
                username=usertest2
                adduser(username,password)
                print("USER CREATED")
                break
            elif checkkey==False:
                print("Username already exists, try again")
                continue
            else:
                print("Error")
                break
    elif ch==3:
        mycon.close()
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. please try once again.")
```

Why is this happening, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to make a column called "key" which is a reserved word in mysql.
Use `` ` `` around key to escape it.

Edit: Remove the `,` in `users, where` under `checkkey()`

Comment: this worked, however, there is another problem, when i tried creating a new user for table. i would really like it if you can find out why too...i am absolutely stumped...

Comment: Check my edit..